# Unique SideKey for each individual message in Restricted mode

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

Is it possible to have a **unique secret** key for each new message added to the channel in **restricted mode**?
If yes, How we can achieve it?

**Desired Scenario:**
Different Messages having different SideKeys on same restricted channel